# ExtJS5 MVVM local store

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

How to properly use MVVM viewmodel store?

List.js:

```
Ext.define('some.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    requires: [
        'some.ListModel'
    ],
    rootVisible : false,
    hideHeaders: true,
    viewModel: {
        type: 'list'
    },
    bind: {store:'{mlists}'},
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: false,
    }]
});
```

ListModel.js:

```
Ext.define('some.ListModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.list',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'
    ],
    stores: {
        mlists: {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: [
                { name: 'id', type: 'int'},
                { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'count' },
                { name: 'group' }
            ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    read: 'php/lists/read.php'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'lists'
                }
            }
        }
   }
});
```

i get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Panel.js?_dc=1404313037482:430
Ext.define.bindStore                            Panel.js?_dc=1404313037482:430
Ext.define.reconfigure                          Table.js?_dc=1404313037482:1417
Ext.define.setStore                             Table.js?_dc=1404313037482:1376
Ext.define.privates.onBindNotify                Bindable.js?_dc=1404313037482:681
Ext.define.privates.notify                      BaseBinding.js?_dc=1404313037482:83
Ext.define.privates.react                       Binding.js?_dc=1404313037482:206
Ext.define.notify                               Scheduler.js?_dc=1404313037482:394
Ext.define.onTick                               Scheduler.js?_dc=1404313037482:425
(anonymous function)                            Function.js?_dc=1404313037482:121
```

Comment: Did you use Sencha Cmd to generate the app?

Comment: @Saki yes. `sencha app build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code:

1. If it is `Sencha Cmd` generated then view someList should be in `view` directory. Of course it would work when it is elsewhere but there must be a good reason not to follow Sencha recommended directory structure. This is not related to the issue.
2. Sencha recommends to start namespace with a capital letter to distinguish from other variables. It should read `Some`, not `some` in this case. It is not related to the issue.
3. `someList` extends `TreePanel` so it must use a `TreeStore`. `mlists` is normal store. It can be cause of the issue.

If you want to define a tree store in ViewModel, configure it with `type:'tree'` config option and do not forget to configure also `root` option that is mandatory for tree stores.

Then you can bind it normally as any other store the way you are already using.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7cb `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: Did you read my answer? If you add `type` and `root` to `mlists` store the error disappear - I've tested it in the fiddle you posted. Of course, no tree is displayed because there is no proxy configured and no data loaded to the store.